# Help center / product or service recommendations

Tags: feature-request, help-center

When voting to close, one of the options available is `Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is...` but some feedback in a post I voted to close is that our position on these types of recommendations is not explicitly mentioned in the help center beyond a brief reference to Software Recommendations.

Can we get something added to the help center that clarifies this?

Comment: It's on the [SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which is constantly linked to.

Comment: Would be nice to have a mention and a link to the blog in the help center though.

Comment: @MikeW - You have some ability to edit parts of the help information as a moderator. Not all of it, mind, but some. :)